No suitable version of Qt was found
I'm trying to install the program Cockatrice on Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, and following the directions to the $ cmake .. step results in the following error.
CMake Error at cmake/FindQtRuntime.cmake:72 (message):
  No suitable version of Qt was found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:214 (include)

I know that I do have it installed; the qmake command shows the options fine. If anyone could help me figure out what I'm doing wrong that would be much appreciated, I'm sure it's something super basic I've just never heard of. Thanks.

a few references as a starting point QT Forums and Raspberry Pi could be of help
